# GeoJSON layer fails to load in OpenLayers

Tags: geojson, openlayers

I have downloaded OpenLayers v6.3.1 libraries and successfully displayed a simple map on my local server, and now I'm trying to load a GeoJSON file as a new vector layer into this map.

But for some reason it's not loading.

Here is what it shows in Chrome :
[image]

And here is the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_cyclo_temp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/ol.css">
    <title>TestMap</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="libraries/ol.js"></script>

    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      

            var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          new ol.layer.VectorImage ({
            visible: true,
            source: new ol.source.Vector ({
              //projection : 'EPSG:3857',
              url: "kml/test.geojson",
              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            }),

          })
            
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([4.8374852,45.7568633]),
          zoom: 12
        })
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the error : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/wamp64/www/cyclo_temp/v2/kml/test.geojson' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
kml/test.geojson:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Most browsers do not allow xhr requests to the C: drive.  To test locally you must either run from localhost or use a browser such as Edge which does allow file protocol xhr.

Comment: You have to use a web server like IIS, Apache, nginx...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, I see you also have WAMP installed, you are just trying to access your webpage the wrong way.

Try http://localhost/cyclo_temp/v2/TestMap.html instead of [file:///C:/wamp64/www/cyclo_temp/v2/TestMap.html](http://file:///C:/wamp64/www/cyclo_temp/v2/TestMap.html)